# UIViewController has gray overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm experiencing a very odd problem. For some reason my UIViewController has a gray overlay. I am using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
bundle: nil];

ProjectDescriptionViewController *detailViewController =
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailView"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:
detailViewController animated:YES];
```

to push the view from a UIViewController in my Storyboard. It detects everything fine, and no errors are thrown, but for some reason the push towards this view is laggy and ends up having a gray overlay! I have went over my code and storyboard many, many times and even compared it to a past project with the same principle. If someone could point me in the right direction as to what might be my problem, that would be great thanks!

here is what I'm [talking](http://imgur.com/B7J5IM9) about
[here is a picture](http://imgur.com/xwLSypi) of my storyboard if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some design issues with your storyboard.

Storyboards apps are embedded in either a UITabBarController or UINavigationController.

UITabBarControllers manage multiple UIViewControllers.  You are using a UITabBarController within the UINavigationController, and your UITabBarControllers are connected from there to multiple UINavigationControllers, so I can see why it is so confused.

I would recommend that you start with the base Tab Bar Controller instead of a navigation controller, then modally present your login screen (without animation) at the start, so that the login screen is "above" your Tab Bar Controller.  Then when they login, just dismiss the login screen.

Then connect your UITabController to the separate UIViewControllers (NOT UINavigationControllers).

[Here is a link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-creating-a-uitabbar-application-with-storyboards/) to a tutorial that may help you with the UITabBarController embedding.

Also, if you really want to stick with a UINavigationController, you can give it a toolbar, whose buttons you could connect to other view controllers.  Just don't have UITabBarControllers and UINavigationControllers where you really want UIViewControllers.

Comment: Well I did find the problem, and it was because (somehow) my UIView's alpha was at .65 for that class. When I fixed it, it worked fine. I will certainly look into everything you are saying! Thanks!

Comment: Also any views that have alpha in them slow down animations.